# Should social media be embedded on a website on mobile?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, social-media

I'm in the process of making a website with an Instagram feed. This is essentially a landing page for a company that sells a service (not ecommerce).

I use a script that detects a the browsers user agent and serves a mobile version of the site if needed. I choose this over media queries because I specifically want to give mobile users a different experience.

The site is one page and has everything they would need; information about the service, social media links & a contact area. While the 'desktop' version does have an Instagram feed, I feel that it might be unwieldy & will certainly take substantially more resources to load even 8 posts from Instagram (I would expect this to double the loading time of the site at the minimum). I'm thinking of leaving it out of the mobile version altogether, as there will still be large & noticeable links that for most users would open up in their respective apps which I think would provide a better experience anyways. Is there any compelling arguments for why I shouldn't do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give only the minimum they have to see on mobile. The more content, the more user frustration. Leave out this Instagram feed for your mobile site.

Keep things super clean and simple, so humans will like being on your site.